# Angular js initialize $http then function working in any case

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my initial angular function. I am setting whrong `http` address and working `http` address, but working `then` function in any case. If I set wrong http address it sholud be handle `catch` function. This is [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/barteloma/4f2g5c9v/).

```
(function () {

    loadAppSettings().then(function () {
        alert(1)
    }).catch(function(){
            alert(0)
    });

    function loadAppSettings() {
        var $http = angular.injector(["ng"]).get("$http");

        return $http.get("oops").then(
            function (response) {
                angular.module("app").constant("appSettings", response.data);
            }
        ).catch(
            function (errorResponse) {
                console.error("app settings couldn't load.")
            }
        );
    }
})();
```

Comment: `catch` function working always. If you remove catch from loadAppSettings then `alert(0)` will works fine. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4f2g5c9v/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of AngularJS do you use ?
Because, in my opinion, the former way of doing that was :

```
$http.get('/someUrl').success( function( data, status, headers, config ){
    // code in case of success
}).error( function( data, status, headers, config ){
    // code in case of error
});
```

(see [1.4.3 $http documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/docs/api/ng/service/$http))

And the new way (since 1.4.4) is :

```
$http.get('/someUrl').then( function( response ){
    // code in case of success
}, function( response ){
    // code in case of error
});
```

(see [1.4.4 $http documentation](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ng/service/$http))

Comment: If you check the script he has linked in the fiddle, it's 1.5.0.

Comment: Ok. So he should use the second way then.

Comment: So, @bookmarker, you should try to use the syntax described in the second part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using Angular version before 1.4.4 - for `$http` calls, the promise returns `.success()` and `.error()` handlers instead, which have extra parameters, instead of `.then()` and `.catch()`.

Try using these function names instead.

In Angular 1.4.4 the different handlers have been deprecated.